# Transfer data to other view when a countdown timer becomes 0 (zero)

Tags: ios, swift

I have searched everywhere, on google, youtube, stackoverflow.

I got many articles showing how to transfer data using a segue.

I have been able to transfer data to another view using a segue when a button is tapped.

What I need is to transfer data (text of a label) to another view when a countdown timer hits 0.

I have a timer starting from 5. I start the timer by calling its function in the `viewDidLoad()` block.

I have another function `counting()` where i check when the timer reaches 0, and when it reaches 0, then is when I want the text of the label (myLabel) to transfer to another view (nextView).

I'm new to iOS Development, I have started learning iOS Development using the Swift Language (as it is identical to C#)

I somehow do not understand the documentation of Apple.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I have posted this question after I failed to find the solution for this anywhere on the Internet.

Code of First view :

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Starting Timer
        startTimer()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func startTimer(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    timerunning = true
    }

    // Variables

    @IBOutlet var myNameText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var myText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!
    var timercount :Int = 5
    var timerunning : Bool = false
    var timer = NSTimer()



func counting(){

timercount -= 1
timerLabel.text = "\(timercount)"

if(timercount == 0)
{
timerunning = false
timer.invalidate()


// Change view and display myNameText on nextView


}

}

override  func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") {
var svc = segue.destinationViewController as secondViewController;
svc.toPass = myText.text

}
}
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? and Swift is no way near to C#

Comment: The problem is how do i transfer the text of the label to another view when the timer hits 0 and also the view should change to 'nextView'

Comment: Is your problem the transfer of the data through the segue, or is it initializing the segue?

Comment: my problem is how to transfer the data to other view when the timer hits 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you need is

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest", sender: self)
```

Put this in after your `timer.invalidate`.  It will programmatically trigger the segue, which will cause the `prepareForSegue` function to be executed and transfer control to the secondViewController.

Comment: Yes i agree this would take me to the other view, I have tested this as well, but by doing this how can i get the text of a label from the first view to the next view ?

Comment: Your line `svc.toPass = myText.text` should be doing that?

Comment: that line is only triggered when i hit a button (another button on the view), what i need is that the data should be transfered when the timer hits 0.

Comment: It should also run when you call self.performSegueWithIdentifier.  Try putting a breakpoint in and stepping through.

Comment: where do i put a breakpoint ? on the `svc.toPass` line? or on the `performSegue` line ?

Comment: To start, put it on the svc.toPass line, and see whether it is triggered when your timer gets to zero.

Comment: Got it. I had to place the initialized variables in the nextView out of the viewDidLoad() block. They were placed in the viewDidLoad block. So the `svc.toPass` line was being shown as an error that the view did not contain any member `toPass` in the other view controller. So I placed the `toPass` variable out of the viewDidLoad() block and it worked like a charm.